# Reordering factor (ordinal) variable in ascending order

Tags: r, forcats

Let's suppose I've got a variable in my data frame that looks like this:

```
x <- rep(seq(10, 50, by = 10), each = 20) %>% factor() %>% forcats::fct_shuffle()
```

Now, I want to reorder the levels in ascending order. Theoretically, I could just use `factor` again and define levels by hand:

```
factor(x, levels = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
```

but it's seems to be cumbersone in a long run, with potentially much more levels. So how can I reorder levels in ascending order?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
factor(x, levels =  sort(levels(x)))

# [1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
# [41] 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40
# [81] 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
# Levels: 10 20 30 40 50
```

With `forcats`:

```
forcats::fct_inorder(x)
```

Data:

```
x <- rep(seq(10, 50, by = 10), each = 20) %>% factor() %>% forcats::fct_shuffle()
```

Comment: However, is there a function from forcats that would do that? `df %>% mutate(x = factor(x, levels = sort(levels(x))))` results in `NA`s

Comment: Yes, see my update. Here a list of useful functions from `forcats` https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html

Comment: FYI your code with `mutate` works fine with me, so maybe try cleaning up your workspace then retry.

Comment: Just noticed that `fct_inorder` doesn't do exactly what I intend as it orders levels according their order of appearance (example output I got: `Levels: 10 < 20 < 30 < 40 < 50 < 5 < 60 < 70 < 100`), while I need to sort levels based on their numeric values (desired: `Levels: 5 < 10 < 20 < 30 < 40 < 50 < 60 < 70 < 100`).

Comment: Then you'll need something like `fct_relevel(x,sort(levels(x)) )` maybe but I don't see the difference with the base R solution..